# Use AMD defined module within 3rd party, non-AMD library

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I have a library - call it **SomeLib** - which is defined to support various module loaders:

```
(function(global, factory) {
    if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
        define([], factory);
    } else if (typeof module !== 'undefined' && module.exports) {
        module.exports = factory();
    } else {
        global.UriTemplate = factory();
    }
})(this, function() {
   ...
   // returns constructor function
});
```

I can easily load it with RequireJS like

```
require.config({
  paths: {
    'theLibrary: '../path/to/the/lib'
  }
});
```

Then I have another 3rd-party library - call it **AnotherLib** - which internally uses SomeLib like

```
var the Lib = new SomeLib(...);
```

That means `SomeLib` has to be available globally.

AnotherLib is just a plain JavaScript module function

```
(function(){
  // the code
})();
```

It is not compliant with particular module loaders.

When I include AnotherLib with RequireJS, I do something like

```
require.config({
  paths: {
    'theLibrary: '../path/to/the/lib',
    'anotherLib: '../path/to/anotherLib'
  },
  shim: {
     'anotherLib: [
        'theLibrary'
     ]
  }
});
```

The **problem is that I get a undefined exception** on the line within AnotherLib where it instantiates SomeLib (`new SomeLib(...)`).
This is because **SomeLib is not defined on the global object** but rather published as an AMD module which AnotherLib doesn't "require".

Can I solve this somehow, or does AnotherLib have to be AMD compliant and properly require SomeLib.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best thing would be to get an AMD-compliant library or to make the library AMD compliant. The latter option would entail modifying the source manually or having a build step that turns the non-AMD-compliant code into a real AMD module. How to do this depends on how the library is designed.

An method that would work with any library is to deliberately leak the symbol that the library requires into the global space:

1. Make `anotherLib` be dependent on a new module, which you could call `SomeLib-leak`.
2. Create the new module. This definition does not have to be in a separate file. I usually place such "glue" modules before my call to `require.config`. The module would be like this:

   ```
   define('SomeLib-leak', ['SomeLib'], function (SomeLib) {
       window.SomeLib = SomeLib;
   });
   ```

   I do purposely have `define` set the module name here. Usually, you don't want to call have `define` set the module name but for "glue" modules that are placed like I indicated above, this is necessary.

By the time `anotherLib` is loaded, `SomeLibrary` will be in the global space.

Comment: That's what I thought as well...Currently discussing (1) with the author of the JS library. (2) would be a possible workaround, although not quite nice. Thx a lot