# log4javascript is undefined when I try to include it using RequireJS

Tags: requirejs, log4javascript

When I use requirejs (v2.1.13) to include log4javascript (v1.4.10) js variable **log4javascript** is undefined however as I can see in chrome network console log4javascript.js is loaded successfully.

Here is my requirejs config:

```
requirejs.config({
'baseUrl': 'resources/js',
'paths': {
    'angular': 'libs/angularjs/angular',
    'jquery' : 'libs/jquery/jquery-2.1.1.min',
    'bootstrap' : 'libs/bootstrap/bootstrap',
    'log4javascript': 'libs/log4javascript/log4javascript_uncompressed'
},
'shim' : {
    'angular' : {'exports' : 'angular', deps: ['jquery']},
    'jquery': {'exports' : 'jquery'},
    'bootstrap': {'exports' : 'bootstrap', deps: ['jquery']}
}});
```

Sine 1.4.10 log4javascript should support AMD so I don't need to add shim.

I can't understand what am I doing wrong. Please help!

UPD: It seems something wrong with AMD support in version 1.4.10, because when I commented out following lines in "log4javascript_uncompressed.js" and added shim, everything became fine:

```
/*
if (typeof define == "function" && define.amd) {
    // AMD. Register as an anonymous module.
    define(factory);
} else if (typeof module != "undefined" && typeof exports == "object") {
    // Node/CommonJS style
    module.exports = factory();
} else {
    // No AMD or CommonJS support so we place log4javascript in (probably) the global variable
*/
    root.log4javascript = factory();
//}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> When I use requirejs (v2.1.13) to include log4javascript (v1.4.10) js variable log4javascript is undefined however as I can see in chrome network console log4javascript.js is loaded successfully.

Which is exactly what would happen if everything is working perfectly. Look at the code you commented out. When log4javascript detects an AMD loader **it does not leak a variable named `log4javascript` into the global space**. It leaks that variable only if it detects neither an AMD loader or that it is running in Node.

If the code that uses log4javascript is all in AMD modules, then the proper way to access log4javascript is to include it as a dependency in the `define` or `require` calls. For instance, `require(['foo', 'log4javascript'], function (foo, log4javascript) {...});`

If you have to work with code that expects a `log4javascript` variable to exist in the global space you *can* work around it by deliberately leaking the variable. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27154465/1906307) for details of how to do it.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Louis! You are definetly right.
Silly me requirejs beginner!